# Cant change font color in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cant seem to change the font color in my navbar, the other elements in my navbar css works but not the font color for some reason. I have tried to change the class but then my other elements in the css wont work. I cant seem to find the problem, though this is my first time using bootstrap.

CSS

```
.navbar  {
background-color: white;
border: none;
color: #0000;

}

.navbar-brand {
font-size: 50px;

}
```

HTML

```
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf=8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar=header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TRAVELLING</a>
        </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `color: #0000;` ==> `color: #000;`

Comment: I agree with @AlonEitan you can also use `color: #000 important!;` to force effects.

Comment: I see what you mean but still didnt work for me, used important!, still didnt work. I tried just putting in red still no change to font color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.navbar  {
background-color: white;
border: none;
color: #000;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav li > a{
  color: orange !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
font-size: 50px;
color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf=8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TRAVELLING</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. so you had to use indivdual classes to change the fonts in the navbar?

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned a wrong value to color property. It should be 3 or 6 digits like `color: #000` or `color: #000000`

CSS

```
.navbar  {
background-color: white;
border: none;
/*color: #0000;*/ color: #000;

}
.navbar ul li > a{
 color: #f00;
 }
```

Comment: I see but tried all that but still didnt help, even used just used words didnt work.

Comment: @user3444694 what you mean is to change the color for your navbar ul li a? or all the link in the navbar?

Comment: you can use this .navbar ul li a{ color: #f00; } or .navbar ul li > a{ color: #f00; }

Answer (score 1):

Code

```
.navbar  {
background-color: white;
border: none;
color: black;
}

.navbar-brand {
font-size: 50px;
}
.navbar a{
color:red;
}
.navbar li a{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inline css in your navbar where you want to change. Try something like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color:white;border:none;color:#000;">
```

Comment: It's not a god practice to do this every time you want to change some styles. Eventually HTML would become a huge pile of confuing mix of markup and styles.

Comment: I agree. But sometimes, you have to do something like this when laziness strikes. Lol

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 .navbar {
  background-color: white !important;
  border: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.navbar *{
  color: #000 !important; // should set font color for element contain text
}
```